# get barcode type from number

Tags: iphone, android, barcode

I want to know bar code type of number example `EAN13,ITF14,CODE128,etc.,`

I have a bar code number `890115700428`

the type of above bar code number is `EAN13`.

I want to know bar code type of bar code number by logically in `android` and `iphone` also with out using scanning.

My app like this if i entered bar code number and then it will show the type of bar ode number.

Is it possible in `android` and `iphone`. If yes how?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: You could probably use code from [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) though I don't have a specific solution for you

Comment: just i want to know what type of bar code number was entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you can't figure this out.  It is possible to reduce the possibilities and in a few cases to figure it out.

A further problem is that many printed barcode numbers are only partial, that is the number provided with a barcode is missing some parts.  Some companies just print enough of the barcode for their own internal use.  Also Codabar rarely prints the leading and trailing letters.

As an example for a 12 digit barcode (123456789012) there are at least 9 common possibilities: UPC-A, Code39, Code128, EAN-13, UPC-E, Codabar(16 variants) Code128-A, Code128-B Code123-C.